# Sending Request from Angular to Java Servlet

Tags: java, angular, servlets, httprequest, angular-httpclient

I have an angular app and a java servlet backend. what I need to do is send httpRequest from angular to backend. I am using httpClient to do that.
MyService.ts

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable()
export class MyServices {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  public getTables(num: number) {
    return this.httpClient.post("url/to/backend",JSON.stringify({number: num}));
  }
}
```

and in my servlet I receive the request but when I use requset.getParameter to get the number value it returns null. I'm sure when I read the request body it returns:

> "{"number":3}"

when I use request.getParametersName it returns null again. does anyone know what I am doing wrong? and am I using the right tool for sending an httpRequest?

Comment: why do you stringify the body?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I tried to do it without stringifying the body but it made no difference.

Comment: Could you solve it? I'm having the exact same problem, with the exact same situation. Reading the body through `getReader()` shows the JSON, but with `getParameter()` I don't seem to be able to get them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try swapping the code to `return this.httpClient.post("url/to/backend",{'number': num});` as you shouldnt stringify the body if the web handler expects a json body

Comment: have you tried logging out the whole body? instead of just what the value is?

Comment: I tried that. I can log out the whole body with getReader(). as I said in the original question it logs "{"number":3"}" . I can use that but I don't think it's very good practice.

Comment: I haven't tried that. do you mean parsing it back using Gson?

Comment: well you said the logged value has quotes around it which suggests its a string, not json

Comment: that's seems logical. but why isn't it json? any ideas?

Comment: my best guess is either the app isnt rebuilding properly when you remove  the stringify or the java server code forces it to be a string

Comment: That helped a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert in this, but when you are sending a request in post method the data is in body. In your servlet you are checking it in request parameter. I think you have to check in request body. I use spring framework than servlet, so can't provide exact code.